# What field type to store the facebook message?

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I have created a simple facebook app and I want to store the facebook message in my mysql database. What field type do I have to use to store the facebook message?

facebook message can be 60,236 chars (or little more i think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TEXT` will hold 65,535 bytes ([source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/maximum-length-mysql-text-field-types/))

Comment: what type should i use for message_tags (user_id and names of tagged in the message).. should i use text for that as well?

Comment: I think that would be overkill. If the user_id is numeric use a numeric data type (`smallint`, `mediumint`, etc) and for names use `varchar`. For that field find out the maximum length of that value and set your `varchar` to that (i.e. `varchar(100)`).

Comment: just one person/page name can be 100 and there will be more than one person names on it with their id. all i can think of its text. following how its there data represented. http://pastie.org/7902531

Comment: Store the ID as `varchar(15)` and name as `varchar(50)`. Give each user their own columns in the database table (sender_id, sender_name, recipient_id, recipient_name). That should cover it.

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. message tags can have many many users / pages tagged with their id and name and return as array from fql table. also same with_tags (assign people that are with user when posting the status)

Comment: In that case put them in their own table. Then you can relate them to the messages as needed.

Comment: hmm i think i will have to explain in detail. i made new post with detail information for tags http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523656/what-field-type-to-store-the-facebook-stream-tags