# What field type to store the facebook stream tags?

Tags: mysql, facebook, facebook-fql

I have created a simple facebook app and I want to store the facebook stream tags in my mysql database with stream infomation. What field type do I have to use to store the facebook stream tags?

Stream Table: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

- description_tags (content match with description field)
- message_tags (content match with message field)
- with_tags
- tagged_ids
- attachment

sample description with description_tags:

```
      "description": "Sanan Umer was tagged in Ar Arslan's photo.", 
      "description_tags": {
        "0": [
          {
            "id": 100000381150973, 
            "name": "Sanan Umer", 
            "offset": 0, 
            "length": 10, 
            "type": "user"
          }
        ], 
        "25": [
          {
            "id": 100000457967257, 
            "name": "Ar Arslan", 
            "offset": 25, 
            "length": 9, 
            "type": "user"
          }
        ]
      },
```

i was thinking to use TEXT field type, but wanted to double check with professionals.

pulling and retriving data for pages / user / groups / event will be faster, if stored all the data in one table. just like fb. just what i was thinking.

Comment: maybe in future, but right now. i prefer to use relational database for now.

Comment: so you wanna cram the whole doc in 1 column ?

Comment: well i have to fetch streams for the user/pages/groups/event, comments, likes and on top getting tags for each field from another table. i think it will slow things down. no?

Comment: i was just trying to understand if you are talking about a blob text or individual columns

Comment: individual columns with TEXT type on those columns.

Comment: i wouldn't use text nor save the offset or length (but then again i don't know what offset means but length seems a little silly). now if you data is actually huge, text could make sense.  http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,105964,105984#msg-105984

Comment: offset and length are used, because the text is UTF-8 and using regular php function for UTF-8 text, function like substr, wont work properly. because some letters are count twice, when its not twice in real UTF-8. offset tells after which position of the text (description or message field) has the following tag started with. doing regular str_ireplace will fail if name of page/group/user/event are same name.

Comment: ok, but those are just part of your stream in. you are not saving them in mysql are you (the offset and length) ?

Comment: have to save them also, because they are useful for building links to the tagged data.

Comment: yeah but your source code uses them to build those links to be saved (in php, ruby, c#, etc). mysql doesnt need them does it, after the fact. just a bunch of extra baggage albeit small

Comment: no, i need to save them and rebuild on request. i'm also including our website feed same way.

Comment: so your data in mysql will see updates later or is the original insert a never to be updated row ? meaning why rebuild them on the fly if they don't change? or if they do change, build them again. you data example is sorta fuzzy in my mind. are you suggesting that later on you missed a tag and need to reprocess, such as "Sanan Umer was tagged in Ar Arslan's photo. And it was tagged by Basit too." And later you need to get Basit ?

Comment: well even facebook avoid building html as for final version of data. it's most likely because the data can be reused for different devices and rather then link to site, the data will be linked to device path's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [BLOB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html) type which is binary safe (so you do not need the additional steps of serializing or unserializing ) but given the structure of you data sounds like you would be much better off with a [Document-oriented DB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) and i recommend using [MongoDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MongoDB) or [CouchDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchDB)

Using a DODB you will have more control over the date which i assume its really what you want.

Comment: you said to use BLOB type and i dont have to do additional steps like serializing or unserializing. how can i store array inside blob then? i been trying to look up on examples, but all of the examples have serialize/unserializing. any link for demo?

Comment: Based on your sample data i assume you receive it in json format which is a string and you can store it directly in a BLOB type column. If the data is in array form and NOT json form then you have 2 options : either json encode the array either serialize it.

Comment: isn't blob is slower (i read somewhere) than TEXT type? also facebook messages are limit to 63,206, so should i use MEDIUMBLOB for storing message, tags, attachment in one column or BLOB is fine?

Comment: Performance wise TEXT and BLOB are pretty much the same. " For BLOB and TEXT data, the information is stored internally in a different area of memory than the row buffer" . You can store them all using `MEDIUMBLOB` or if its an advantage you can store them separately one column for each one (message,tag, attachement). The must important thing is what do you want to do with this data besides storing it ?

Comment: retrieve and show again to user. is there any performance hit on using BLOB or MEDIUMBLOB?

Comment: It depends on the data size stored in each one , if the data size is the same the performance will be roughly the same but if you store the data at max size for each one (2^16 blob and 2^24 mediumblob) i suspect there will be a performance hit . If you want to know exactly i recommend you to do a benchmark

Comment: also take a look at this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: does it make any difference to use MEDIUMBLOB or MEDIUMTEXT?

Comment: the only difference is that `BLOB` type treats the string in a binary way : "BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values. TEXT values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set."

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in TEXT and use serialization and unserialization.